# Can I fix the alpha display problems on material viewport on new Blender 2.73?

Tags: materials, 3d-view, transparency

I'm making a Low poly model for videogame, but I got some problems on displaying 8bit alpha (partialy tranparent pixels) in material viewport in Blender 2.72b. Now in Blender 2.73a some of these bugs was fixed, that was great, but some other appeared too.

[image: 8 bit alpha bugs in material viewport]

As you can see, the partially transparent pixels from the plane with a round ring texture of the goggles are clipping through the red lens that are right behind it.

This bug doesn't occur while in edit mode. And this didn't happen in 2.72b.

And in the Left view (3rd frame), the light wire from his exoskeleton clip through the other wire from the other leg. But not viewing from the right view (4th frame).
and these occurs no mater the backface/normal direction.

Of course none of these bugs are shown on render. But i was worried about porting these models for a game engine like Unity and get the same problems.

Do I need to worry about this on viewport? If yes. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The second part of [my answer to this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10634/how-do-i-create-a-single-object-with-two-different-texture-and-uv-maps/10641#10641) might be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to worry about this on viewport?

No, I don't think so. The external game engine will be using it's own rendering pipeline, so any problems with the rendering then will be a separate and unrelated issue (with the possible exception of a problem with the data itself, e.g. double faces resulting in Z fighting etc. However this doesn't seem like the case here).

> Is there a way to fix it?

Try enabling *Transparent* in *Properties > Object > Display* on all the objects with transparency.

Comment: @ganfal3 : The other guy maddin45 on comments section helped a lot. Now I know that's because the "z-culling". and there's no way to fix it on blender viewport, I'll just leave the to worry about z-culling on game engine.
Thanks a lot!